# Cargando data de firebase - firestore y angular 8

Tags: angular, cli

```html
 <div class="row" *ngFor="let usuario of user">
                <div class="col-9" *ngIf="editState == false">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="user">
                                <h2 class="namekey">{{usuario.namekey}}</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="descripcion">
                                <h5>Desciption</h5>
                                <p>{{usuario.description}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="type">
                                <h5>Type</h5>
                                <p>{{usuario.type}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sensivity">
                                <h5>Sensitivity</h5>
                                <p>{{usuario.sensitivity}}</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Consulta estoy cargando data de firebase y usando firestore al ingresar por primera vez la data carga correctamente cuando cambio de link o otra pestaña y regreso a la vista anterior la data no carga, si uso el menu con routerlink, la data no carga hasta refrescar la pagina o hacer f5. dejo el link y se requiere dejo el código. uso collection con firestore.

no entiendo a que se debe.

https://joselo01.github.io/testcase/#/manage

Saludos

```js
// component
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../../interfaces/user.interface';
import { UserServices } from '../../services/users.service';
import { Possible } from '../../interfaces/possible.interface';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-manager',
  templateUrl: './manager.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./manager.component.scss']
})
export class ManagerComponent implements OnInit {

user: User[];
editState = false;
userToEdit: User;
  constructor(private userServices: UserServices) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userServices.getUser().subscribe( user => {
      console.log(user);
      this.user = user;
    });
  }

  clearState() {
    this.editState = false;
    this.userToEdit = null;
  }

}


// SERVICIOS METODOS

  getUser() {
    return this.user;
  }

  addUser(user: User) {
    this.userCollection.add(user);
  }

  updateUser(user: User) {
    this.userDoc = this.afs.doc(`user/${user.id}`);
    this.userDoc.update(user);
  }
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar el código de `getUser` en `UserServices` ?

Comment: no me deja poner mas código del servicio. en getUser tengo esto  getUser() {
    return this.user;
  }

Comment: puedes hacerlo con suscribe, pero firebase tiene una libreria para eso de hecho no tienes que programar el reload , ya que el mismo lo hace, [mira este enlace](https://fireship.io/snippets/install-angularfire/)

Comment: @SixtoMujica Ya veo... Entonces `this.user` dentro de `UserService` es un Observable, verdad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### En resumen:

La primer vez que te suscribís a un `Observable`, se consume la data que posee. La segunda vez que te suscribís, tenés que esperar por data nueva.

### Tu código:

En `UserService` guardas el `user` como un `Observable`:

```js
export class UserServices {
  constructor( public afs: AngularFirestore) {
    //... Variables y lógica...
    this.user = this.userCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map (a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as User;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );
  }

  getUser() {
    return this.user;
  }
// .... resto de la clase
}
```

En tu componente inyectás el servicio y llamás `getUser()`, te devuelve el observable `user` y te suscribís a él:

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userServices.getUser().subscribe( user => {
      console.log(user);
      this.user = user;
    });
  }
```

OK...! Entonces lo que pasa es que un [`Observable` normal (un `Subject`) no repite sus valores anteriores.](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/). Cuando te suscribes por primera vez, se ejecuta el código y los suscriptores que existan hasta ese momento reciben los datos. Si después de devolver datos, se recibe un nuevo suscriptor, éste tendrá que esperar por nuevos datos para ser incluido en la transmisión.

### La solución:

Bueno, una de las soluciones. Es crear un nuevo `Observable` cada vez que lo necesités:

```js
  getUser() {
    return this.userCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map (a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as User;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );
  }
```

Pero entonces debés cuidar [el correcto uso de observables en tu componente](https://www.twilio.com/blog/prevent-memory-leaks-angular-observable-ngondestroy).

Lo mejor, creo que sería guardar el usuario como variable normal:

```
export class UserServices {
  private user: User;
  constructor( public afs: AngularFirestore) {
    //... Variables y lógica...
    this.userCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map (a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as User;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      })).subscribe(us => this.user = us);
    );
  }

  getUser(): User {
    return this.user;
  }
// .... resto de la clase
}
```

Comment: lo resolví en código en getUser() creando un nuevo observable en el get.